# Equality of boxed boolean

Tags: java, primitive, autoboxing

Quick question: is it guaranteed that this code always prints `true`?

```
Boolean b1 = true;
Boolean b2 = true;
System.out.println(b1 == b2);
```

Boxing of boolean seems to result in the same Boolean object all the time, but I couldn't find too much info about boxed Boolean equality in JLS. On contrary, it even seems to suggest that boxing is supposed to create new objects and may even result in OOM exceptions.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: `new Boolean(true)` won't equal other boxed booleans, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification on Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to
>   corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the
>   following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> - From type `boolean` to type `Boolean`
>
> [...]
>
> **If the value `p` being boxed is** an integer literal of type `int` between
>   `-128` and `127` inclusive (§3.10.1), or the **`boolean` literal `true` or `false` (§3.10.3)**, or a character literal between `'\u0000'` and `'\u007f'`
>   inclusive (§3.10.4), **then let `a` and `b` be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `a == b`.**

This is relatively simply [implemented](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Boolean.java#Boolean.valueOf%28boolean%29) as

```
/**
 * The {@code Boolean} object corresponding to the primitive
 * value {@code true}.
 */
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);

/**
 * The {@code Boolean} object corresponding to the primitive
 * value {@code false}.
 */
public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);

public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return (b ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
```

Comment: thnx, overlooked that part

Comment: but I guess it's not guaranteed that `Boolean.TRUE == true` right?

Comment: @OlegMikheev Yes it is, see [JLS 15.21.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.2). In that case `Boolean.TRUE` is unboxed to `true` so you get `true == true`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The compiler automatically translates this:

```
Boolean b1 = true;
```

into this:

```
Boolean b1 = Boolean.valueOf(true);
```

which always returns one of the two constants `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`.